# Picking up how many entries in a json array

Tags: php, html, file-get-contents, json

I use the following code to extract information from a json page.

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://fantasy.mlssoccer.com/web/api/elements/498/');
$jsonarray = json_decode($str, true);

$week1 = $jsonarray['fixture_history']['summary'][0][2];
$week2 = $jsonarray['fixture_history']['summary'][1][2];
```

Here's an excerpt of what it's taking from

```
{ "summary" : 
    [ 
        [ 1, "PHI (A)", 14 ]
        [ 2, "TOR (A)", 8 ]
    ]
}
```

At the moment only 2 weeks exist. 1 new entry will be added every week. How do I code something to say "loop for however many weeks/entries exist"?

Pretty much what I want to do is put this info into a HTML table and I want the code to know how many weeks are in there. There will be 1 row of data for each week.

Let me know if this isn't clear.. and thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.length`

**In Javascript**

```
jsonObj['summary'].length
```

**In PHP**

```
echo count($jsonarray['fixture_history']['summary']);
```

Comment: Looks like this is what I need. How do I use it in my example though? I tried `echo $jsonarray['fixture_history']['summary'].length;` and it returns the word `Arraylength`. Is there a way to get it to return a simple number? (should be 2 in this case)

Comment: @Cully see undated answer.

Comment: Excellent. Works perfectly. Sorry, I should have mentioned PHP. I know very little about javascript. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [`count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php), which gives you the length of the array.  Use that in a for-loop for a condition, and you should have your answer.

```
$arr_length = count($arr);
```